# How to run the following Powershell command in java?

Tags: java, powershell, cmd

I am trying to run a powershell command which starts the tomcat service.Currently the command is working perfectly when executed directly through the windows powershell. However if i run the same command from java i get and error saying

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'net'.

my powershell command is:

```
Start-Process -verb runas cmd -ArgumentList "/k net start Tomcat7"
```

my java code:

```
final String PS_COMMAND = " powershell.exe  Start-Process -verb runas cmd -ArgumentList /k net start Tomcat7   " ;
Process p=  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PS_COMMAND);
 BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
             String l;
             while((l=BR.readLine()) != null){
                 System.out.print(l);
             }
```

Comment: Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), not Runtime.exec.  Make sure you pass exactly six strings.

Comment: @Alfabravo With the last edition it looks like valuable information is lost, was it intentional?

Comment: i have edited and have put the java code back!!

Comment: @VGR how do i achieve this using process builder??

Comment: @lalo no! I think we edited at the very same time. I just formatted PS command and error message but the java code was added while I was editing and it got lost. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Alfabravo its okay!!

Answer (score 3):

Runtime.exec is obsolete.  Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe",
    "Start-Process", "-verb", "runas", "cmd", "-ArgumentList", "/k net start Tomcat7");
Process p = builder.inheritIO().start();
int exitCode = p.waitFor();
```

The call to [inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) will make the process’s output show in the Java program’s output, so there is no need to read and print the Process’s InputStream.

Comment: do we need to add powershell.exe also??

Comment: iam still getting the error :Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'net'.

Comment: Does this one have a minimum Java version to run?

Comment: I just noticed that I forgot the powershell.exe argument.  Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @Alfabravo As the documentation to which I linked states, ProcessBuilder has been a part of Java SE since Java 1.5.

Comment: @VGR executing the command opens UAC dialog, how can we bypass that?

Comment: @nikhilbansal By running as administrator.  I would be surprised if there were any other way, since the whole point of UAC is to stop programs from secretly gaining elevated privileges.

Comment: @VGR My use case is to start a c++ process from a java application on any condition and further interact with it. My c++ projects implement Microsoft's HttpServer API which requires the c++ app to be run as an administrator. My java program is a server code and provides API toa mobile application. 
Mobile --> Java application  --> c++ applicaiton and vice versa.

Thatswhy I need to bypass UAC because that would require manual interaction.